# Создание JScrollBar через наследование BasicScrollBarUI. Прозрачность Track

Tags: java, gui

Здравствуйте. Хочу сделать свой скролл-бар, но хотелось бы, чтобы элемент thumb был полосой белого цвета, а track - прозрачный. Привожу пример картинки (белый прямоугольник - это thumb). Но вот не знаю как сделать его прозрачным? Возможно кто-то сталкивался с таким? 
[image: Пример скролл-бара]

```
public class MyScrollBar extends BasicScrollBarUI {
    private JButton b = new JButton(){
        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(0, 0);
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected JButton createIncreaseButton(int orientation) {
        return b;
    }

    @Override
    protected JButton createDecreaseButton(int orientation) {
        return b;
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintThumb(Graphics g, JComponent c, Rectangle thumbBounds) {
        g.translate(thumbBounds.x,thumbBounds.y);
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillRect(0,0,thumbBounds.width,thumbBounds.height);
    }


    @Override
    protected void paintTrack(Graphics g, JComponent c, Rectangle trackBounds) {
        g.translate(trackBounds.x, trackBounds.y);
        g.setColor(new Color(255,255,255,0));
        g.drawRect(0,0,trackBounds.width,trackBounds.height);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize(JComponent c) {
        Dimension dim = super.getPreferredSize(c);
        return new Dimension(8,dim.height);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getMaximumSize(JComponent c) {
        Dimension dim = super.getPreferredSize(c);
        return new Dimension(8,dim.height);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй `scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().setOpaque(false);`.